# Javascript Array giving incorrect length, inconsistent output

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I am developing a simple frontend file reader to read in a 20x15 map (row x column) to send to the backend. However, I am facing some issues due to the inconsistencies *(shown below, input 1 vs input 2)* in the output of my code. I have logged out the values and realized that although each line has only 15 characters, the arr.length=16 until the last line for input1.

My code snippet is as shown here which is triggered on-click.

```
function readFile (evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var file = files[0];           
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            var list = event.target.result.split("\n");
            console.log(list.length);
           
            map = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                console.log(list[i].length)
                console.log(list[i])
                map[i] = Array.from(list[i].split("").map(Number));
              }
            socket.emit('load_map', {loaded_map: map});
            console.log("Sent loaded map to backend");
            
            drawMap(resetMap());
            console.log("Loaded map in frontend UI");
        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
        
     };
```

When I use input 1,

```
000000001100000
000000000000000
000000000000000
111100000000000
000100010000000
000000001000000
000000000100000
000000000010000
000100000010000
111100000010000
000100000000000
000000000000000
000000000000000
000000000000001
000000000000001
000011111100001
000000000000000
000000000000000
000000000000000
000000011100000
```

I get the following output,

```
20
16
000000001100000
16
000000000000000
...
15
000000011100000
```

When I use input 2,

```
000000000100000
010000000000000
000000000000000
000001000000000
000000000111000
000100000000000
000100000000000
000100000000000
000100000000000
000100000001000
000100000001000
000000000001000
000000000001000
000000000001000
000000000001000
000111000000000
000000000100000
000000000000000
000000000000010
000001000000000
```

I get the following output,

```
20
15
000000000100000
15
010000000000000
...
15
000001000000000
```

Can someone enlighten me why this might be happening?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Check your input works for me https://jsbin.com/runawevowi/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think the problem is that there is invisible whitespaces. I have included ```.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]/g, '')``` to solve this issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

**That’s not the *array* length, that’s the *string* length of each line.**

There is likely trailing whitespace, which usually does not make it through being copied on this site — usually resulting in “it works here” when others try it.

It might even be an invisible whitespace character, including a \r without \n.

To check trailing whitespace (won’t check invisible), an easy-to-remember approach is to use some framing character:

```
console.log("[" + str + "]")
```

Once the source of the error is identified, it might be sufficient simply to [trim the lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).